# “Value of Type ‘[]’ has no member ‘’” error when iterating over an array in SwiftUI using ForEach

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-foreach

I am writing an app to track the distances that golf clubs hit a ball. I have a little experience in Python but I am very beginner with Swift and SwiftUI.

I have a .Swift file that contains the array I want to use to store my data.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct Club: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let clubName: String
    let yards: Int
    let strokesCounted: Int
}

struct ClubList {
    static var inTheBag = [
        Club(clubName: "Driver", yards: 250, strokesCounted: 0),
        Club(clubName: "Putter", yards: 10, strokesCounted: 0),
        Club(clubName: "3 Hybrid", yards: 180, strokesCounted: 0)
    ]
}
```

I am working on a view now that will take an input from the user and add the input to this array as “clubName: user input, yards: 0, strokesCounted: 0” and display the array as a list under the text entry box. I was able to do this when I was using a list only containing the names of the clubs a strings, but now that I have added the additional properties it doesn’t work anymore.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddAClub: View {
    @State private var usedWords = [String] ()
    @State private var newClub: String = ""
    var body: some View {
        List {
            Section{
                TextField("Which club would you like to add?", text: $newClub)
                    .onSubmit(addNewClub)
            }
            Section {
                
                ForEach(ClubList.inTheBag.Club.clubName) {
                    word in Text(word)
//>”Value of Type ‘[Club]’ has no member ‘Club’”
                }
            }
        }
    }; func addNewClub() {
        let answer = newClub.lowercased().trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        guard answer.count > 0 else {return}
        withAnimation {
            let newClubFull = [Club(clubName: answer, yards: 0, strokesCounted: 0)]
            ClubList.inTheBag.append(contentsOf: newClubFull)
        }
        newClub = ""
    }
}
```

I have tried various changes to the argument for ForEach in the second section of the View. For example: inTheBag.Club.clubName, ClubList.inTheBag.clubname, Club, clubName, etc.

I would like to take the user input and add it to the array as a new Club with yards: 0 and strokesCounted: 0 (this may be working as the func addNewClub() shows no errors). I would also like to display the list of clubNames below the text entry as it updates.

Comment: `ForEach(ClubList.inTheBag, id: \.clubName) { club in Text(club.clubName) }`. Unrelated but consider to rename `clubName` as `name`, club is redundant.

Comment: @vadian This worked! Thanks for your help. Good point about clubName, I'll change that. Also, should my code be actually adding a new entry to ClubList.Swift or will it only add to the list while in the AddAClub view? From what I can see it is only adding to the view, not to the ClubList file, but I'm unsure if thats just a simulation issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@vadian answered my question in a comment.

```
ForEach(ClubList.inTheBag, id: \.clubName) { club in Text(club.clubName) }
```

Unrelated but consider to rename `clubName` as name, club is redundant.